# How can i get default saved id of perticular record using SugarORM?

Tags: android

hi I have implement sugar orm for sql transaction in my application.I want to fetch default id generated by sugar orm of particular record.please help me.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in Advance.I am using below link for sugar orm.

https://github.com/satyan/sugar

i am using following code for fetch id of particular record

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<>();
        books.add(new Book("Title here 1", "1st edition"));
        books.add(new Book("Title here 2", "2nd edition"));
        books.add(new Book("Title here 3", "3rd edition"));
        SugarRecord.saveInTx(books);

        //update
        Book book = Book.findById(Book.class,1);
        book.title = "john smith";
        book.save();

        List<Book> booksone = Book.findWithQuery(Book.class,"Select id from Book where title = ?","john smith");
```